# Get number of distinct records with same key

Tags: oracle11g

Let's assume I have a table A:

```
|  ID    | B_ID |  C    |  column 1  | ...   | column x|
|  1     | 24   |   44  |   xxxxxxx
|  2     | 25   |   55  |   xxxxxxx
|  3     | 25   |   66  |   xxxxxxx (data in all other columns are the same)
|  4     | 26   |   77  |   xxxxxxx
|  4     | 26   |   78  |   xxxxxxx
|  4     | 26   |   79  |   xxxxxxx
```

I want to get highest number of distinct records with same `B_ID` (and I also want to know `B_ID` where this occurs). So in this example I want to get values 3 and 26.

What would be best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is a simple aggregation + ordering + limiting the number of rows returned to 1:

```
select b_id, no_of_records
from (
    select b_id, count(1) as no_of_records
    from table_A
    group by b_id
    order by no_of_records desc
)
where rownum <= 1;
```

This, of course, returns 1 row even if you have multiple groups with the same highest number of records. If you want all groups with the same highest number of records, then the approach is slightly different ...

```
select b_id, no_of_records
from (
    select b_id, count(1) as no_of_records,
        rank() over (partition by null order by count(1) desc) as rank$
    from table_A
    group by b_id
)
where rank$ <= 1;
```